# Some Browsers do not load CSS and Layout of Components[Joomla]

Tags: css, joomla, load, joomla-component

The problem is that I have a responsive site, based on ***joomla*** framework. It works fine on all browser and all the custom components load easily but I have noticed that it has a problem on some *mobile browsers* (as: ASUS device, browser integrated on Facebook APP and more) to load a `CSS` of page, linked to *mijoshop* component. In fact this component work fine and loads `CSS` in some mobile browser but other show text and blank page.

For help and better understanding I have attached a video demo:

[**Video Link1**](https://youtu.be/7EnBiWGXQ8s)

[**Video Link2**](https://youtu.be/D1gUydqpeeI)

How can I fix? Thanks!!!
And for first thanks for support :)

Answer (score 0):

The first idea came to my mind is that viewport in browser that doesn't load(or load but doesn't show, check in devtools responsive mode) css file differs from bottom value of pixels in media query. I mean than your design could be without base.css file, css rules work for example from 320px and some browsers have viewport value less than 320 px, so nothing is displayed.

Comment: I @nazar and thanks for help!
How can veify that? How found base.css?
Anyhow the same css template is correctly load for the other page of the site, only on the page of the mijoshop component dosen't